# Datatable scroll with server side processing?

Tags: ajax, datatables, scrollbar

I have below code

With this  I see data gets loaded first time and scroll is displayed. But when i hit scroll bar  ajax call does not  go to server ?

Also once ajax call goes, how to display the json data retuned from server ? I did not get any good example on google related to scrolling with
server side processing ?

```
function(){
       oTable=      $('#customerTable').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "iDisplayStart":0,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']],
                    "sScrollY": "600px",
                    "iScrollLoadGap": 50,
                    "sAjaxSource": "custom_url",
                     "ajax" : {
                                "url" : "custom_url"
                                "type" : "GET",
                                "data" : function(d) {

                                }
                            },
                    "aoColumns": [
                    {"aTargets": [0],"sName":"customer.fullName", "mData": function(response){
                        return response.customer.fullName;
                    }, "bSortable": false},
                    {"aTargets": [1],"sName":"updatedDate", "mData": function(response){
                        var updateDate = response.updatedDt;
                        return updateDate;
                    }, "bSortable": true},

                    ]

                    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {


                            }
                        });
            }
```